# Maintain Paragraph Indentation even after Image Ends

Tags: html, css

I am a beginner in HTML/CSS. I am trying to write a paragraph on side of image. But when paragraph reaches end of container it goes to next line but does not respect the indentation.

What I want to achieve is:

```
IMG Paragraph Text Paragraph Text
    Paragraph Text Paragraph Text
    Paragraph Text Paragraph Text
```

What Happens now:

```
IMG Paragraph Text Paragraph Text
Paragraph Text Paragraph Text
Paragraph Text Paragraph Text
```

Please refer to image below:

[image]

Any Help would be appreciated

Comment: show us your html / css code. Firt guess that a `display: flex` on the outer element should help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say we are taking a container to make them side by side. In markup there are few ways to do such thing. Let's take a container `div.`

```
<div class='container'>
</div>
```

inside of this container we are gonna have our image and paragraph.

```
<div class='container'>
    <div>
      <img src='' alt='img'/>
    </div>

    <div>
      <p>Your paragraph here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

to have them side by side let's add some css:

```
<style>
  .container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 1rem;
  }
</style>
```

Explaination :

> When we used `display:grid;` it will be in side by side and take same width as other one takes. And `grid-template-columns` will make them aligned. Hope you understand

Comment: Please fully explain your answer. Don't just dump code and expect everyone to understand what you're suggesting

Comment: Thanks for your answer, would i need 3 paragraph tags, won't the paragraph line break and go into new line?

Comment: Yeah @simoncowell you can do it.